# 2 AlarmManager conflict on an event

Tags: android

i have 1 Activity, 1 Broadcastreceiver and 1 service

the activity create 2 alarmclocks

```
//Config calendar for StartTime
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);       

        //Set Alarm for StartTime
        Intent alarmI = new Intent(AddRule.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmI.putExtra("Stream", "Start");
        pIntent_start = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmI, pIntent_start.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager aM_start = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        aM_start.set(aM_start.RTC, c.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent_start);

        //Config calendar for EndTime
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();

        c1.set(Calendar.YEAR, year_end);
        c1.set(Calendar.MONTH, month_end);
        c1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day_end);
        c1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour_end);
        c1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute_end);
        c1.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

        //Set Alarm for StartTime
        Intent alarmII = new Intent(AddRule.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmII.putExtra("Stream", "End");
        pIntent_end = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alarmII, pIntent_end.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager aM_end = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        aM_end.set(aM_end.RTC, c1.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent_end);
```

1 alarmclock should signal the beginning of an event, and one the end.

the only action of the broadcastreceiver is to send the the intent to the service,

on my service class i look if the intent extra is start or end and then decide what to do...

```
if(intent.getStringExtra("Stream").equalsIgnoreCase("Start"))
    {
        //do something
    }
    else if (intent.getStringExtra("Stream").equalsIgnoreCase("End"));
    {
        //do something
    }
```

the problem i found out is, when the time is reached and the service is activated, the start and end signal are fired both and so the action which should happen on start is only for a very short period of time until the end signal is fired.
On the Endtime when the Signal should be fired the app crashes because of the one_shot.
I already checked time and all the things but its alright :/ i'dont see the problem, can somebody help me ?

sorry for my pour english

moritz